# What is using all of my Android's RAM?

Tags: gratis, android

So, I juts got a new 'phone. It's China-no-name, but I bought it from Amazon.

I have used it for 1 day. I did install 15 or 20 apps, but was careful to select SD card as data storage for them where I had a choice.

It is saying that 63.7 gB of 64gB is used. BUT, when it gives me a list of usage (apps/images/videos/etc), that doesn't even total 4gB.

How can I discover what it using all of my RAM? The 'phone is running Android 11. Can anyone recommend an app?

I have a preference for a visual map, something like this

[image]

but will accept an answer without - e.g with only a list (but I hope that the list is sortable by size).

It would be a great bonus if the app could move the data form internal to SD card, but I imagine that it would then have to inform the app & I don't remember enough about android coding to know if that is doable.

Comment: In your question you speak about [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory), but I think you mean Flash memory. To my knowledge there is no Android device with 64GB RAM. As far as I know maximum is about 12-16 GB. Only devices with 64 GB flash memory are sold at the moment (some times called ROM which is also wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot meets [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) – also available [at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.google.android.diskusage/) but unfortunately not updated since 2017, so it's not sure it will work with the changed storage permission system on Android 10+. Other [similar apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_storageanalysis#group_161) known to me are not open-source and are either not updated in a while as well, or come with a bunch of trackers – so it's hard to give a real recommendation while keeping a clear conscience .

Comment: Thanks, as always, for a great recommendation, Izzy. I kept your conscience clean by using the F-Droid version of DiskUsage :-)

Comment: Looking at F-Droid first is always a wise approach :D